# Why does ActionEvent ask for an id?

Tags: java, undefined-behavior

When making a `new ActionEvent`, you're required to provide an integer as an `id`. The documentation says that this is:

> An integer that identifies the event. For information on allowable values, see the class description for `ActionEvent`

And the class description for ActionEvent says:

> An unspecified behavior will be caused if the `id` parameter of any particular `ActionEvent` instance is not in the range from `ACTION_FIRST` to `ACTION_LAST`.

My confusion comes in with the values of `ACTION_FIRST` and `ACTION_LAST`:

```java
/**
 * The first number in the range of ids used for action events.
 */
public static final int ACTION_FIRST                = 1001;

/**
 * The last number in the range of ids used for action events.
 */
public static final int ACTION_LAST                 = 1001;
```

**If `id` must always be `1001` lest unspecified behavior occur, then why even require it?**

Comment: "When making a `new ActionListener`" -- do you perhaps mean `ActionEvent`?

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom yes, sorry. Fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ActionEvent` is a subclass of `AWTEvent`, who is the owner of the id.  The constructor for `ActionEvent` simply passes the id to super's constructor, where super (...) then checks that it's one of:

- ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED
- ItemEvent.ITEM_STATE_CHANGED
- AdjustmentEvent.ADJUSTMENT_VALUE_CHANGED
- TextEvent.TEXT_VALUE_CHANGED

So, `ActionEvent` wants to ensure that super only gets an `ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED` from him, where ACTION_PERFORMED is a constant set to ACTION_FIRST).

Comment: Perhaps you can illuminate the reason why the id field, according to the official doc, must fall between ACTION_FIRST and ACTION_LAST, yet both constants are 1001.

Comment: <rant>IMHO this was a poor design. Super classes shouldn't know about subclass stuff.</rant> My guess is that they wanted a range for checking inputs before passing to super (but doesn't look like was ever implemented), and since super is only expecting one kind from sub, the max and min values were the same. Perhaps it's a leftover from logic in a previous version of the class, but couldn't remove it since those constants are public and they wanted to be backwards-compatible. Just a guess.

Comment: @splungebob Why, then, doesn't it just pass `ACTION_PERFORMED` to `super` and never ask for it in the constructor?

Comment: @splungebob also, yeah... the entire AWT system is messed up and poorly-planned, but I think that speaks well of the era in which it was designed, and means that we should praise them for doing something useful with it by extending it into the Swing system instead of trashing it and starting from scratch.

Comment: Java is such a hoary, old language that other JVM based languages have sprung up to fix its weaknesses, yet I'm surprised again and again at how many strange artifacts from 1995 continue to exist to this day.